# can't plot predict line in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm using those data :

```
'data.frame':   1584 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Individual: Factor w/ 3 levels "AG201","AG202",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Used      : Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ NDVI      : int  4724 4576 4894 4297 4670 4932 4346 3810 3481 4058 ...
```

I'm doing a glm with "NDVI" as a continuous explanatory variable, and then I'm plotting the model through the scatterplot of the data (I'm reproducing the same script as in the R book, Crawley, p.596)

```
model<-glm(Used~NDVI,binomial);
xv<-seq(0,10000,0.2);
yv<-predict(model,list(NDVI=xv),type="response");
plot(NDVI,Used);
lines(xv,yv);
```

My problem is that no line appears on my graph...

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Did you look at yv? Are range(xv) and range(yv) inside your axis limits?

Comment: At a guess, you have a factor for the y-axis (See `$Used` in the output from `str()`). This has not drawn the plot you think it has. See what the user coordinates of the plot are with `par("usr")` **after** you draw the plot, and then look at `range(yv)` and that will hopefully enlighten you. You want a continous plot covering range 0, ..., 1 and you may not be getting that when you plot a factor on the y-axis.

Comment: You have obviously also executed an `attach(dfrm)` which is generally not advisable, but if you are going to use `attach`, you should include it with your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

Following Gavin's insight, here's a suggestion:

```
plot(NDVI, as.numeric(Used)-1 )
lines(xv,yv)
```

Factors are integer vectors starting at `1L` with assignments by default in alpha order of the labels. So you should be OK with "no" < "yes" leading to the No's being 1 and hte Yes's being 2 and then shifting down to the correct scale [0,1]. You may need to also look at `str(yv)`